Laravel cURL error 35: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer on HTTP request
I'm encountering an issue in my Laravel application where a POST request to an external API (Telegram Bot API) is failing with the following error:
cURL error 35: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

I have set up a simple route to trigger a Telegram bot message using Laravel's Http client:
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

Route::get('bot', function (Request $request) {
    $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot<my-token>/sendMessage';

    Http::connectTimeout(20)->post($url, [
        'chat_id' => '<chat-id>',
        'text' => 'Got a new request!'
    ]);
});

When I open the URL manually with the necessary query parameters, it works as expected and sends the message to the Telegram chat. However, when making the request within Laravel, I receive the above cURL error.
What I Have Tried:

Checked URL and Parameters: Manually accessing the URL with query string parameters works fine, so the API URL is correct.
SSL Verification: I attempted disabling SSL verification temporarily:
Http::withOptions(['verify' => false])

but I still encountered the same error.
Setting Specific SSL/TLS Version: I tried enforcing TLS 1.2:
Http::withOptions(['curl' => [CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2]])



I've also tried to use Client (GuzzleHttp\Client) too. But same error occurs..
Environment Details:

Laravel Version: 11.2
Ubuntu Version: 24.04 LTS
cURL Version: 8.5.0
PHP Version: 8.3.6
Nginx Version: 1.24.0

Thanks in advance

SOLVED: I just needed to turn on a VPN (because Telegram is unavaiable in my country)
I used Nekoray and then I tried to use it's proxy on my request. check the below code:
    $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/<token>/sendMessage';
    Http::withOptions([
        'proxy' => '127.0.0.1:2081'
    ])->connectTimeout(20)->post($url, [
        'chat_id' => <chat_id>,
        'text' => 'Got a new request!'
    ]);

